# Can I marshal System.Object as an inaccessible pointer to C and then back to C#?

Tags: c#, pointers, interop

In C I have a function which registers a callback and a state object and then passes the state object to the callback every time it is called, much like `EventHandler<EventArgs>` works in C#. I have a class in C# that registers a managed callback with the C function and currently passes `IntPtr.Zero` and I simply do not use it because I have not found a good and clean way of passing a managed object reference to C and getting it back to C#.

I do not want the managed object to be accessible in C, I just want to pass it to C and have it passed back (verbatim) to the managed callback every time it is called from C.

Looking for the "right" way of doing this, basically.

Here is my delegate for the callack:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)]
internal delegate IntPtr LuaAllocator(
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)] object args,
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)] IntPtr ptr,
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)] IntPtr originalSize,
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)] IntPtr newSize);
```

Here is the current `DllImport` I'm doing:

```
    [DllImport(DllName, EntryPoint = "lua_newstate", ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SysInt)]
    public static extern IntPtr NewState(
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] LuaAllocator allocator,
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)] object args);
```

And the error I'm getting right now is:

> MarshalDirectiveException was unhandled:
>   Cannot marshal 'parameter #1': AsAny cannot be used on return types, ByRef parameters, ArrayWithOffset, or parameters passed from unmanaged to managed.

This error goes away if I keep the delegate's first argument as an `IntPtr` and use `MarshalAs.SysInt` but I then cannot reconstruct the managed object, but I do get with a value other than `IntPtr.Zero` which is curious and may be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution. The `HandleRef` comment pointed me to `GCHandle` which I'm already familiar with but had never done this with. By making a non-pinned `GCHandle` from the object you want to marshal you can call the static `GCHandle.ToIntPtr(GCHandle)` method to acquire an `IntPtr` representing that particular handle. Inside the callback I called `GCHandle.FromIntPtr(IntPtr)` to re-acquire the handle and then retrieved the `System.Object` from the `GCHandle.Target` property.

Here's how you set up the callback and the state object:

```
// Omitted
string test = "This is a test string.";
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(test, GCHandleType.Normal);
LuaCore.NewState(allocateCallback, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(handle));
// Omitted
```

And here is how you utilize it in the callback:

```
private IntPtr Allocate(IntPtr sender, IntPtr ptr, IntPtr originalSize, IntPtr newSize)
{
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(sender);
    string test = handle.Target as string;

    // Omitted
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is [`System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khk3k17t.aspx).  You can allocate a `GCHandle` and convert it to a `System.IntPtr`.  When you get it back, you can use `GCHandle.FromIntPtr` to get your `GCHandle` back, and from there, get a proper reference to the original `object`.

**Caveat**

There are potential issues using this method revolving around garbage collection and the variables that you are allocating.  As is customary with Platform Invoke, you need to make sure that some things you allocate aren't collected.  The parameter to `GCHandle.Alloc` should be  cached somewhere with a strong reference, and of course, you will need to prevent the collection of the delegate that you pass to whatever native function you're calling. Also, note that the `GCHandle` must be freed when you are done with it to prevent memory leaks.

Below is an example demonstrating the procedure.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.IO;
public delegate bool InteropCallback(int handle, System.IntPtr payload);

public class InteropApp
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool EnumWindows(InteropCallback cb, System.IntPtr payload);

    public static void Main()
    {
        var tw = System.Console.Out;
        var twhandle = GCHandle.Alloc(tw);

        InteropCallback cb = CallbackFunc;

        EnumWindows(cb, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(twhandle));
        twhandle.Free();
    }

    private static bool CallbackFunc(int handle, System.IntPtr payload)
    {
        var gch = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(payload);
        var tw = (TextWriter)gch.Target;
        tw.WriteLine(handle);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `GCHandle.Alloc` maintain a strong reference already and avoid the need for a cached reference?

Comment: @JNZ It doesn't seem to be documented, so it would be foolish to depend on it.

Comment: Actually, it is documented multiple times in the GCHandle documentation, for example in the return type description of the 1-argument constructor: "A new GCHandle that protects the object from garbage collection."

Comment: @SebastianRedl I'm having trouble remembering so long ago, but it looks like my comment was aimed at JNZ rather than Mr. Gray. Feel free to edit my answer if it is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use [`HandleRef`](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.handleref) instead of `IntPtr`, if I understand correctly.

Comment: The problem with that becomes that I do not have a handle for the object to feed to the `HandleRef`.